# Wordpress Customer Query Pagination With Query Strings Vars

Tags: php, wordpress

I have code as shown below to paginate my Wordpress custom query code which it successfully does. The issue I'm having is on the page I have some links to order the posts by different fields.

After I have clicked these links the paginated links are then wrong, the paginated part gets added to the end, the link ends up like this http://ideation/pagination/?c=General+Improvement/page/2/ where it should look like this http://ideation/pagination/page/2/?c=General+Improvement

The pagination code I have is as follows, any direction would be appreciated.

```
<?php
global $wp_rewrite, $wp_query, $max_page, $page;
$wp_query->query_vars['paged'] > 1 ? $current = $wp_query->query_vars['paged'] : $current = 1;

$pagination = array(
'base' => @add_query_arg('page', '%#%'),
'format' => '/page/%#%',
'total' => $max_num_pages,
'current' => $current,
'prev_text' => __('PREV'),
'next_text' => __('NEXT'),
'end_size' => 1,
'mid_size' => 2,
'show_all' => false,
'type' => 'list'
);

if ($wp_rewrite->using_permalinks())
$pagination['base'] = user_trailingslashit(trailingslashit(remove_query_arg('s', get_pagenum_link(1))) . 'page/%#%/', 'paged');

if (!empty($wp_query->query_vars['s']))
    $pagination['add_args'] = array(
    's' => get_query_var('s')
 );

echo paginate_links($pagination);
?>
```

Comment: what happens if you make 'format' = > '/page/%#%'

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Are you flushing permalinks whenever you try a new change?